# Hide/Show lightbox

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/x1m5x0p8/14/

Clicando em Lustra Embalagem 01 abrirá um lightbox e clicando na seta para direita dentro desse lightbox abre outro, porém não fecha o primeiro. E clicando na seta(qq uma) do segundo lightbox, não volta para o primeiro. O que preciso é fechar o primeiro ao abrir o segundo e vice-versa. Valeu!

Alguma imagens substitui por umas alternativas porque o conteudo não está no ar ainda